# Redireccionar al login en react

Tags: reactjs, login, redirección, jwt, local-storage

me encuentro implementando el login de una aplicación en React que utiliza un jwt guardado en el localStorage para verificar si el usuario está logueado. Al intentar ingresar a la url  ¨/home¨, el componente correspondiente (Home) verifica que si el jwt no se encuentra en el localStorage la aplicación debe redireccionar al login, pero me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
Warning: You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on: "/login"
```

Este error me es devuelto  siempre y sin importar cualquiera que sea la ruta a la que desee redireccionar. Adjunto código de Login, Home y Router. Gracias de antemano.

```
//Router
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Login from '../components/Login';
import Register from '../components/Register';
import Home from '../components/Home';

const Router = () => (
 <BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
   <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
   <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
   <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
   <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
  </Switch>
 </BrowserRouter>
);

export default Router;
```

```
//Login
```

```js
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Form, Icon, Input, Button, Checkbox } from 'antd';
import { GlobalStyle } from './Styles';
import { userLog } from '../FetchServer';
import { Redirect, BrowserRouter, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

class Login extends Component {
 handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.props.form.validateFields(async (err, values) => {
   if (!err) {
    console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
    var token = await userLog(values);
    console.log(token.data);
    if (token) {
     localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(token.data));
     window.location = '/home';
    }
   }
  });
 };

 render() {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  const tokenParse = JSON.parse(token);

  const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
  return (
   <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
     {tokenParse && <Redirect to="/home" />}
     <GlobalStyle id="components-form-demo-normal-login">
      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="login-form">
       <Form.Item>
        {getFieldDecorator('userName', {
         rules: [ { required: true, message: 'Please input your username!' } ]
        })(
         <Input
          prefix={<Icon type="user" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />}
          placeholder="Username"
         />
        )}
       </Form.Item>
       <Form.Item>
        {getFieldDecorator('password', {
         rules: [ { required: true, message: 'Please input your Password!' } ]
        })(
         <Input
          prefix={<Icon type="lock" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />}
          type="password"
          placeholder="Password"
         />
        )}
       </Form.Item>
       <Form.Item>
        {getFieldDecorator('remember', {
         valuePropName: 'checked',
         initialValue: true
        })(<Checkbox>Remember me</Checkbox>)}
        <a className="login-form-forgot" href="register">
         Forgot password
        </a>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" className="login-form-button">
         Log in
        </Button>
        Or <a href="/register">register now!</a>
       </Form.Item>
      </Form>
     </GlobalStyle>
    </Switch>
   </BrowserRouter>
  );
 }
}

const WrappedNormalLoginForm = Form.create({ name: 'normal_login' })(Login);

ReactDOM.render(<WrappedNormalLoginForm />, document.getElementById('root'));

export default WrappedNormalLoginForm;
```

```
//Home
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Out from './Out';
import { Redirect, BrowserRouter, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

class Home extends Component {
 render() {
  const token1 = localStorage.getItem('token');
  const tokenParse1 = JSON.parse(token1);

  return (
   <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
     {!tokenParse1 && <Redirect to="/login" />}
     <div>
      <p>Usted está logueado</p>
      <Out />
     </div>
    </Switch>
   </BrowserRouter>
  );
 }
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A la hora de re direccionar tenemos muchas opciones, yo estaba utilizando "`Redirect`" y "`window.location`", pero después de darle una oportunidad a "withRouter"(`import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';`) y a "history"(`this.props.history.push('/url');`), me he dado cuenta de que el código se reduce en unas cuantas líneas y son menos los aspectos que hay que tener en cuenta para lograr los objetivos a la hora de redireccionar. Adjunto debajo el código de los archivos iniciales en la pregunta, pero ahora con los cambios referentes a la nueva forma de re direccionar que utilicé.

```js
//Router
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Login from '../components/Login';
import Register from '../components/Register';
import Home from '../components/Home';
import Aux from '../components/Aux';

const Router = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
            <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/aux" component={Aux} />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

export default Router;
```

```js
//Login
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Form, Icon, Input, Button, Checkbox } from 'antd';
import { GlobalStyle } from './Styles';
import { userLog } from '../FetchServer';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class Login extends Component {
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.form.validateFields(async (err, values) => {
            if (!err) {
                var token = await userLog(values);
                if (token) {
                    localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(token.data));
                    this.props.history.push('/home');
                }
            }
        });
    };

    goTo = () => {
        return this.props.history.push('/register');
    };

    verifyRoute = () => {
        if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
            return this.props.history.push('/home');
        }
    };

    render() {
        this.verifyRoute();
        const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
        return (
            <GlobalStyle id="components-form-demo-normal-login">
                <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="login-form">
                    <Form.Item>
                        {getFieldDecorator('userName', {
                            rules: [ { required: true, message: 'Please input your username!' } ]
                        })(
                            <Input
                                prefix={<Icon type="user" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />}
                                placeholder="Username"
                            />
                        )}
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item>
                        {getFieldDecorator('password', {
                            rules: [ { required: true, message: 'Please input your Password!' } ]
                        })(
                            <Input
                                prefix={<Icon type="lock" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />}
                                type="password"
                                placeholder="Password"
                            />
                        )}
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item>
                        {getFieldDecorator('remember', {
                            valuePropName: 'checked',
                            initialValue: true
                        })(<Checkbox>Remember me</Checkbox>)}
                        <a className="login-form-forgot" href="register">
                            Forgot password
                        </a>
                        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" className="login-form-button">
                            Log in
                        </Button>
                        Or{' '}
                        <p type="link" onClick={this.goTo}>
                            register now!
                        </p>
                    </Form.Item>
                </Form>
            </GlobalStyle>
        );
    }
}

const WrappedNormalLoginForm = Form.create({ name: 'normal_login' })(Login);

export default withRouter(WrappedNormalLoginForm);
```

```js
//Home
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Out from './Out';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class Home extends Component {
    verifyRoute = () => {
        if (!localStorage.getItem('token')) {
            return this.props.history.push('/login');
        }
    };
    render() {
        this.verifyRoute();
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Usted está logueado</p>
                <Out />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(Home);
```