# Redireccionamiento login react

Tags: reactjs

estoy en una aplicacion que hasta ahora tiene la vista login ya creada, la logica se maneja a traves de context api. Cuando se envian los datos al servicio (`graphql`), me retorna el objeto con la data y el token de la autenticacion. Hasta alli todo muy bien por lo que coloco el token en `local storage`.

Lo que esta pasando es que si bien me redirecciona a la ruta de acceso, este no me cambia la vista a no ser que yo refresque la pagina, la redireccion lo hago en la misma funcion a traves de `history.push("ruta")`. Por alli lei que quizas pueda ayudar a crear un condicional ternario con la variable loggedIn almacenada en el objeto state pero no me funciono.

---

*Aparte de esto*, tengo una duda, si yo seteo el token en local storage, por cada vista que se entre, se debera corroborar el token o quizas una variable con loggedIn en local storage, existe alguna manera que esa data persista sin la necesidad de crear una funcion que verifique ello?

---

Mi archivo context esta configurado de la siguiente manera:

```
    // React
    import React from 'react';

    // React apollo
    import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
    import compose from 'lodash.flowright';

    // Mutations
    import mutations from './graph-queries/mutations';

    // App context
    export const Context = React.createContext();

    class AppProvider extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                store: {
                    loginData: {
                        email: '',
                        password: ''
                    },
                },
                actions: {
                    loginData: this.loginData,
                    signIn: this.signIn
                }
            }
        }

        loginData = (e) => {
            const { name, value } = e.target;
            const { store: { loginData } } = this.state;

            const inputData = { [name]: value };
            const newData = { ...loginData, ...inputData };
            
            this.setState({
                store: {
                    loginData: newData
                }
            });
        }

        signIn = async(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const { store: { loginData, loggedIn } } = this.state;
            const { signinUser, history } = this.props;

            const variables = {
                email: loginData.email,
                password: loginData.password
            };
            
            try {
                const response = await signinUser({variables});
                
                if(response) {
                const { data: {signinUser:{token}} } = response;
                localStorage.setItem('token', token);
                }

                history.push('/books/home');    
                
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }


    

        render() {
            return(
                <Context.Provider value={this.state}>
                    {this.props.children}
                </Context.Provider>
            );
        }
    }

    export default compose(
        graphql(mutations.signinUser, { name: 'signinUser' }),
        /* graphql(mutations.createUser, { name: 'createUser' }) */
    )(AppProvider);
```

Y el archivo routes de esta otra:

```
// React
import React from 'react';

// React-router-dom
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

// Views
import Home from '../views/home';
import SignUp from '../views/signup';
import SignIn from '../views/signin';
import BookHome from '../views/bookviews/bookshome';

// React-router
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';


class Routes extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
          <Switch>
            <Route
              path="/"
              component={Home} exact/>
            <Route
              path="/signup"
              component={SignUp} />
            <Route
              path="/signin"
              component={SignIn} 
            />
            <Route
              path="/books/home"
              component={BookHome} 
            />
          </Switch>
    );
  }
}
export default Routes;
```

Comment: Yo hace un tiempo estuve trabajando con react y tuve un caso muy similar, en estos momentos estoy un poco desvinculado de esa maravillosa tecnología, pero aquí te dejo este enlace donde puedes ver una pregunta con su respuesta acerca de esto de redireccionar al login. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/251293/redireccionar-al-login-en-react/251665#251665

Comment: hola, @ELLEO, gracias por la pronta respuesta efectivamente me faltaba withRouter para estos efectos.